# Dynamic message display

Tags: jsf

```
Set<String> testPopUp = new HashSet<String>()
 //getter
  public Set<String> gettestPopUp() {
        return testPopUp;
    }
//setter
 public void settestPopUp(Set<String> testPopUp ) {
        this.testPopUp = testPopUp ;
 }

<h:alertPopup id="popupMessagesId" title="Error" message="#{testBean.testPopUp }" icon="info">
<h:a4jButton id="popUp" value="Ok" onclick="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('popupMessagesId')"/>                       
</h:alertPopup>
```

Now my Java Code :

TestBean.java :

```
public void test(){ 
 //validation methods 
 testPopUp.add("This is an error");
 AjaxCommandBean.showPopupOnComplete("popupMessagesId");
 }
```

Now, the popup is showing NULL value, as getter : gettestPopUp() is called when the page is loaded, and at that time testPopUp will be NULL. testPopUp is populated only after test() method is executed. So, when I load the page second time I am getting the value. 
Please let me know how can I get the value first time in pop up.
I am using JSF2.0

Comment: `<h:alertPopup>`? `<h:a4jButton>`? Huh? Are you attempting to write guessed code off top of head instead of copypasting real and tested code? This really isn't helpful and only introduces red herrings.

Comment: @BalusC-We have customized libraries that's why I replaced it.  Please let me know if you need any more information apart from this ?